# How to Implement a user and user account with data for iOS

Tags: ios, database, facebook, cocoa, instagram

I'm currently making an app for iOS, I have successfully integrated the facebook SDK and i'm able to login with facebook. In my app, people can post, like, and comment on other posts. Now I have no idea how to do this or even how it will work. Please if someone could concisely explain to me how it could be done.

For Example how does Instagram work when you log in with facebook, does it have a database and just use a facebook user as an id on that database to get data or what ? Thanks a millionnn !

P.s I know this is quite a broad topic but no matter how small you can explain, it would be gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instagram and app like that have there on database and first time we login there with facebook a user will be created in their db (there will be userid and all like a user registered normally) and the posting like comment and all are managed with that user in there db.